# Spark SQL add column/update-accumulate value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame:

```
name,email,phone,country
------------------------------------------------
[Mike,mike@example.com,+91-9999999999,Italy]
[Alex,alex@example.com,+91-9999999998,France]
[John,john@example.com,+1-1111111111,United States]
[Donald,donald@example.com,+1-2222222222,United States]
[Dan,dan@example.com,+91-9999444999,Poland]
[Scott,scott@example.com,+91-9111999998,Spain]
[Rob,rob@example.com,+91-9114444998,Italy]
```

exposed as temp table `tagged_users`:

```
resultDf.createOrReplaceTempView("tagged_users")
```

I need to add additional column `tag` to this DataFrame and assign calculated tags by different SQL conditions, which are described in the following map(key - tag name, value - condition for `WHERE` clause)

```
val tags = Map(
  "big" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries)",
  "medium" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries)",
  //2000 other different tags and conditions
  "sometag" -> "name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'"
  )
```

I have the following DataFrames(as data dictionaries) in order to be able to use them in SQL query:

```
Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("big_countries")
Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("medium_countries")
```

I want to test each line in my `tagged_users` table and assign it appropriate tags. I tried to implement the following logic in order to achieve it:

```
tags.foreach {
  case (tag, tagCondition) => {
    resultDf = spark.sql(buildTagQuery(tag, tagCondition, "tagged_users"))
       .withColumn("tag", lit(tag).cast(StringType))
  }
}

def buildTagQuery(tag: String, tagCondition: String, table: String): String = {
    f"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $tagCondition"
}
```

but right now I don't know how to accumulate tags and not override them. Right now as the result I have the following DataFrame:

```
name,email,phone,country,tag
Dan,dan@example.com,+91-9999444999,Poland,medium
Scott,scott@example.com,+91-9111999998,Spain,medium
```

but I need something like:

```
name,email,phone,country,tag
Mike,mike@example.com,+91-9999999999,Italy,big
Alex,alex@example.com,+91-9999999998,France,big
John,john@example.com,+1-1111111111,United States,big
Donald,donald@example.com,+1-2222222222,United States,(big|sometag)
Dan,dan@example.com,+91-9999444999,Poland,medium
Scott,scott@example.com,+91-9111999998,Spain,(big|medium)
Rob,rob@example.com,+91-9114444998,Italy,big
```

Please note that `Donal` should have 2 tags `(big|sometag)` and `Scott` should have 2 tags `(big|medium)`.

Please show how to implement it.

**UPDATED**

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate();

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("big_countries")
Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("medium_countries")

val df = Seq(
  ("Mike", "mike@example.com", "+91-9999999999", "Italy"),
  ("Alex", "alex@example.com", "+91-9999999998", "France"),
  ("John", "john@example.com", "+1-1111111111", "United States"),
  ("Donald", "donald@example.com", "+1-2222222222", "United States"),
  ("Dan", "dan@example.com", "+91-9999444999", "Poland"),
  ("Scott", "scott@example.com", "+91-9111999998", "Spain"),
  ("Rob", "rob@example.com", "+91-9114444998", "Italy")).toDF("name", "email", "phone", "country")

df.collect.foreach(println)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tagged_users")

val tags = Map(
  "big" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries)",
  "medium" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries)",
  "sometag" -> "name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'")

val sep_tag = tags.map((x) => { s"when array_contains(" + x._1 + ", country) then '" + x._1 + "' " }).mkString

val combine_sel_tag1 = tags.map((x) => { s" array_contains(" + x._1 + ",country) " }).mkString(" and ")

val combine_sel_tag2 = tags.map((x) => x._1).mkString(" '(", "|", ")' ")

val combine_sel_all = " case when " + combine_sel_tag1 + " then " + combine_sel_tag2 + sep_tag + " end as tags "

val crosqry = tags.map((x) => { s" cross join ( select collect_list(country) as " + x._1 + " from " + x._1 + "_countries) " + x._1 + "  " }).mkString

val qry = " select name,email,phone,country, " + combine_sel_all + " from tagged_users " + crosqry

spark.sql(qry).show

spark.stop()
```

fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'sometag_countries' not found in database 'default';
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalog$class.requireTableExists(ExternalCatalog.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.requireTableExists(InMemoryCatalog.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.getTable(InMemoryCatalog.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.getTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:730)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: Why not have a countries table with two columns, country name and description? Description could be a single value from (small, medium, big, big|medium, small|medium). Then you just need to join the two tables on country name.

Comment: Because this is just a particular case. According to the system design, users through the UI can configure as many tags, as they want(need) with the different conditions and names

Comment: The same is true for the collections like `big_countries`, `medium_countries`.  users through the UI can configure as many collections with different names and elements as they need and use the reference to them in their SQL queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this DF solution:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("Mike","mike@example.com","+91-9999999999","Italy"),
     | ("Alex","alex@example.com","+91-9999999998","France"),
     | ("John","john@example.com","+1-1111111111","United States"),
     | ("Donald","donald@example.com","+1-2222222222","United States"),
     | ("Dan","dan@example.com","+91-9999444999","Poland"),
     | ("Scott","scott@example.com","+91-9111999998","Spain"),
     | ("Rob","rob@example.com","+91-9114444998","Italy")
     | ).toDF("name","email","phone","country")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, email: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val dfbc=Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country")
dfbc: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [country: string]

scala> val dfmc=Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country")
dfmc: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [country: string]

scala> val dfbc2=dfbc.agg(collect_list('country).as("bcountry"))
dfbc2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [bcountry: array<string>]

scala> val dfmc2=dfmc.agg(collect_list('country).as("mcountry"))
dfmc2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [mcountry: array<string>]

scala> val df2=df.crossJoin(dfbc2).crossJoin(dfmc2)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, email: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df2.selectExpr("*","case when array_contains(bcountry,country) and array_contains(mcountry,country) then '(big|medium)' when array_contains(bcountry,country) then 'big' when array_contains(mcountry,country) then 'medium' else 'none' end as `tags`").select("name","email","phone","country","tags").show(false)
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|name  |email             |phone         |country      |tags        |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|Mike  |mike@example.com  |+91-9999999999|Italy        |big         |
|Alex  |alex@example.com  |+91-9999999998|France       |big         |
|John  |john@example.com  |+1-1111111111 |United States|big         |
|Donald|donald@example.com|+1-2222222222 |United States|big         |
|Dan   |dan@example.com   |+91-9999444999|Poland       |medium      |
|Scott |scott@example.com |+91-9111999998|Spain        |(big|medium)|
|Rob   |rob@example.com   |+91-9114444998|Italy        |big         |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+


scala>
```

**SQL approach**

```
scala> Seq(("Mike","mike@example.com","+91-9999999999","Italy"),
     |       ("Alex","alex@example.com","+91-9999999998","France"),
     |       ("John","john@example.com","+1-1111111111","United States"),
     |       ("Donald","donald@example.com","+1-2222222222","United States"),
     |       ("Dan","dan@example.com","+91-9999444999","Poland"),
     |       ("Scott","scott@example.com","+91-9111999998","Spain"),
     |       ("Rob","rob@example.com","+91-9114444998","Italy")
     |       ).toDF("name","email","phone","country").createOrReplaceTempView("tagged_users")

scala> Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("big_countries")

scala> Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("medium_countries")

scala> spark.sql(""" select name,email,phone,country,case when array_contains(bc,country) and array_contains(mc,country) then '(big|medium)' when array_contains(bc,country) then 'big' when array_contains(mc,country) then 'medium' else 'none' end as tags from tagged_users cross join ( select collect_list(country) as bc from big_countries ) b cross join ( select collect_list(country) as mc from medium_countries ) c """).show(false)
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|name  |email             |phone         |country      |tags        |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|Mike  |mike@example.com  |+91-9999999999|Italy        |big         |
|Alex  |alex@example.com  |+91-9999999998|France       |big         |
|John  |john@example.com  |+1-1111111111 |United States|big         |
|Donald|donald@example.com|+1-2222222222 |United States|big         |
|Dan   |dan@example.com   |+91-9999444999|Poland       |medium      |
|Scott |scott@example.com |+91-9111999998|Spain        |(big|medium)|
|Rob   |rob@example.com   |+91-9114444998|Italy        |big         |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+


scala>
```

**Iterating through the tags**

```
scala> val tags = Map(
     |   "big" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries)",
     |   "medium" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries)")
tags: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(big -> country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries), medium -> country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries))

scala> val sep_tag = tags.map( (x) => { s"when array_contains("+x._1+", country) then '" + x._1 + "' " } ).mkString
sep_tag: String = "when array_contains(big, country) then 'big' when array_contains(medium, country) then 'medium' "

scala> val combine_sel_tag1 = tags.map( (x) => { s" array_contains("+x._1+",country) " } ).mkString(" and ")
combine_sel_tag1: String = " array_contains(big,country)  and  array_contains(medium,country) "

scala> val combine_sel_tag2 = tags.map( (x) => x._1 ).mkString(" '(","|", ")' ")
combine_sel_tag2: String = " '(big|medium)' "

scala> val combine_sel_all = " case when " + combine_sel_tag1 + " then " + combine_sel_tag2 +  sep_tag + " end as tags "
combine_sel_all: String = " case when  array_contains(big,country)  and  array_contains(medium,country)  then  '(big|medium)' when array_contains(big, country) then 'big' when array_contains(medium, country) then 'medium'  end as tags "

scala> val crosqry = tags.map( (x) => { s" cross join ( select collect_list(country) as "+x._1+" from "+x._1+"_countries) "+ x._1 + "  " } ).mkString
crosqry: String = " cross join ( select collect_list(country) as big from big_countries) big   cross join ( select collect_list(country) as medium from medium_countries) medium  "

scala> val qry = " select name,email,phone,country, " + combine_sel_all + " from tagged_users " + crosqry
qry: String = " select name,email,phone,country,  case when  array_contains(big,country)  and  array_contains(medium,country)  then  '(big|medium)' when array_contains(big, country) then 'big' when array_contains(medium, country) then 'medium'  end as tags  from tagged_users  cross join ( select collect_list(country) as big from big_countries) big   cross join ( select collect_list(country) as medium from medium_countries) medium  "

scala> spark.sql(qry).show
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|  name|             email|         phone|      country|        tags|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|        Italy|         big|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|         big|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|         big|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|         big|
|   Dan|   dan@example.com|+91-9999444999|       Poland|      medium|
| Scott| scott@example.com|+91-9111999998|        Spain|(big|medium)|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|+91-9114444998|        Italy|         big|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+


scala>
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
scala> Seq(("Mike","mike@example.com","+91-9999999999","Italy"),
     | ("Alex","alex@example.com","+91-9999999998","France"),
     | ("John","john@example.com","+1-1111111111","United States"),
     | ("Donald","donald@example.com","+1-2222222222","United States"),
     | ("Dan","dan@example.com","+91-9999444999","Poland"),
     | ("Scott","scott@example.com","+91-9111999998","Spain"),
     | ("Rob","rob@example.com","+91-9114444998","Italy")
     | ).toDF("name","email","phone","country").createOrReplaceTempView("tagged_users")

scala> Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("big_countries")

scala> Seq("Poland", "Hungary", "Spain").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("medium_countries")

scala> val tags = Map(
     |   "big" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries)",
     |   "medium" -> "country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries)",
     |   "sometag" -> "name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'")
tags: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(big -> country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries), medium -> country IN (SELECT * FROM medium_countries), sometag -> name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222')

scala> val sql_tags = tags.map( x => { val p = x._2.trim.toUpperCase.split(" ");
     | val qry = if(p.contains("IN") && p.contains("FROM"))
     | s" case when array_contains((select collect_list("+p.head +") from " + p.last.replaceAll("[)]","")+ " ), " +p.head + " ) then '" + x._1 + " ' else '' end " + x._1 + " "
     | else
     | " case when " + x._2 + " then '" + x._1 + " ' else '' end " + x._1 + " ";
     | qry } ).mkString(",")
sql_tags: String = " case when array_contains((select collect_list(COUNTRY) from BIG_COUNTRIES ), COUNTRY ) then 'big ' else '' end big , case when array_contains((select collect_list(COUNTRY) from MEDIUM_COUNTRIES ), COUNTRY ) then 'medium ' else '' end medium , case when name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222' then 'sometag ' else '' end sometag "

scala> val outer_query = tags.map( x=> x._1).mkString(" regexp_replace(trim(concat(", ",", " )),' ','|') tags ")
outer_query: String = " regexp_replace(trim(concat(big,medium,sometag )),' ','|') tags "

scala> spark.sql(" select name,email, country, " + outer_query + " from ( select name,email, country ," + sql_tags + "   from tagged_users ) " ).show
+------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|  name|             email|      country|       tags|
+------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|        Italy|        big|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|       France|        big|
|  John|  john@example.com|United States|        big|
|Donald|donald@example.com|United States|big|sometag|
|   Dan|   dan@example.com|       Poland|     medium|
| Scott| scott@example.com|        Spain| big|medium|
|   Rob|   rob@example.com|        Italy|        big|
+------+------------------+-------------+-----------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can have 200 or 1000 different tags in the map, so the hardcoding of `case when array_contains(bcountry,country)` will not work I think. Also, according to the system design, I'm limited to use SQL queries and not Spark API for the WHERE conditions

Comment: Thanks, but I can’t hardcode tag sets in SQL query. The tags collections must be accumulated during iterating through the map and evaluating the tag conditions

Comment: @alexanoid.. I just updated assuming we have tag table names as "<tag>"_countries and constructed the qry string. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologize, probably I was not clear previously. I have updated my question with the new `tags` map. The tag condition can be much complex and can significantly differ from one each other. It can condition based on multiple columns and formulas... it's up to the user to specify the condition he/she wants. Taking this into account, will your approach work in this case?

Comment: Yes.. if you see, the tags are not hardcoded anywhere..driven dynamically and the queries are built step by step into a final query.

Comment: Also, I'm using the cross join after doing a collect_list on the tags table which converts it into a single row.. so effective you are doing only <number_of_rows> in tagged_users * 1 * 1 joins only for 2 tags

Comment: please see my updated answer. I have added your implementation with additional tag and now it fails with the following exception: `Table or view 'sometag_countries' not found in database 'default'` But I don't need `sometag_countries` table and the condition for this tag is `name = 'Donald' AND email = 'donald@example.com' AND phone = '+1-2222222222'`

Comment: the conditions are not following a pattern.. have to redesign.. give me some time

Comment: Yeah.. there is no single pattern in the conditions. They can contain any SQL statements allowed in WHERE clause

Comment: @alexanoid.. pls check the UPDATE2 now.. btw spark doesn't allow "country IN (SELECT * FROM big_countries)" as select expression, so I have to modify that as "array_contains((select collect_list(country) FROM medium_countries) ,country) "

Answer (score 1):

If you need to aggregate the results and not just execute each query perhaps use map instead of foreach then union the results

```
 val o = tags.map {
  case (tag, tagCondition) => {
    val resultDf = spark.sql(buildTagQuery(tag, tagCondition, "tagged_users"))
      .withColumn("tag", new Column("blah"))
    resultDf
  }
}

o.foldLeft(o.head) {
  case (acc, df) => acc.union(df)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please comment, how this approach will work from the performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

I would define multiple tags tables with columns value, tag.

Then your tags definition would be a collection say Seq[(String, String] where the first tuple element is the column on which the tag is calculated.

Lets say

```
Seq(
  "country" -> "bigCountries", // Columns [country, bigCountry]
  "country" -> "mediumCountries", // Columns [country, mediumCountry]
  "email" -> "hotmailLosers" // [country, hotmailLoser]
)
```

Then iterate through this list, left join each table on the relevant column with the associated column.

After joining each table simply select your tags column to be the current value + the joined column if it is not null.

Comment: I can’t do the left join or any other joins because the condition for the particular tag evaluation can much complex and based on multiple columns